# Inconsistent Blowfish encrypted data with OpenSSL C++ library and PHP

Tags: php, c++, encryption, openssl

I am trying to develop a C++ program that encrypts some data to later be decrypted with an PHP based Web Service. However, I am having trouble decrypting the data with PHP using Blow-fish CBC method by using the openssl_decrypt() method in PHP.

I am testing this code C++ code to encrypt the message and convert to base64 format to decrypt with my PHP program. Here is the code for the C++ program.

```
#include <secureinfra.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    cout << "Unit Test for the crypto system" << endl;
    SecureInfrastructure mySec;

    /* A 256 bit key and IV */
    auto *key = (unsigned char *)"ZdOAq0yn6H1i35TywbLrtqBO4NCjh7Vh";
    auto *iv = (unsigned char *)"01234567";

    /* Message to be encrypted */
    auto *plaintext = (unsigned char *)"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

    /* Buffer for ciphertext. Ensure the buffer is long enough for the ciphertext which may be longer than the
     * plaintext, depending on the algorithm and mode. */
    unsigned char ciphertext[128];

    /* Buffer for the decrypted text */
    unsigned char decryptedtext[128];
    int decryptedtext_len, ciphertext_len;

    /* Encrypt the plaintext */
    ciphertext_len = mySec.EncryptMessage(plaintext, strlen((char *) plaintext), key, iv, ciphertext);

    /* Decrypt the ciphertext */
    decryptedtext_len = mySec.DecryptMessage(ciphertext, ciphertext_len, key, iv, decryptedtext);

    /* Add a NULL terminator. We are expecting printable text */
    decryptedtext[decryptedtext_len] = '\0';

    /* Show the encrypted and decrypted text in base64 format */
    string encryptedText = mySec.base64_encode(string(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ciphertext)));
    cout << "Encrypted text (base64) is:\n" << encryptedText << endl;
    cout << "Decrypted text (base64) is:\n" << mySec.base64_encode(string(reinterpret_cast<char*>(decryptedtext))) << endl;

    /* Show the decoded decrypted text */
    cout << "Decoded Decrypted text is:" << endl;
    cout << decryptedtext << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My PHP test code for decryption only is presented below:

```
<?php
$ciphertext = "ljRvLcfBiDwxRSm1lDXMwDk5S4pRCg9D2F9jxR5C5yy79xoBHQNKjA/FaQ2dNfKvyO0uilZ/";
$key = "ZdOAq0yn6H1i35TywbLrtqBO4NCjh7Vh";
$cipher = "bf-cbc";

if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods()))
{
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $iv = "01234567";
    // print some parameters
    echo "IV size: ".strlen($iv)."\n";
    echo "Key Used: ".$key."\n";
    echo "Enc Message: ".$ciphertext."\n";
    // Now try to decrypt message...
    $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv);
    echo "Dec Message: ".$original_plaintext."\n";
}
else
{
    echo "The ".$cipher." is not present in the system...";
}
?>
```

However, the PHP program is failing to decrypt the $ciphertext that was generated by my C++ program. It is showing nothing when I try to echo the $original_plaintext.

Also, I noticed that the PHP and C++ encryption with SSL are differing. For example, when I try to encrypt the phrase "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" with PHP (using the openssl_encrypt method) and C++, with the same key and IV, the encrypted base64 string are these below:

in C++: 
ljRvLcfBiDwxRSm1lDXMwDk5S4pRCg9D2F9jxR5C5yy79xoBHQNKjA/FaQ2dNfKvyH3brAV/

in PHP: 
hWj7F1fnBXhIWv4sonjhSmJgHWJALFecxxrGe0T1kLrN4TfSMUw/uELj6h5+Laph

How should I fix this? I saw a similar post describing that I need to set the key size on the C++ program but I am not sure in how to do this correctly.

EDIT: Here is the method that encrypts the message in C++

```
int SecureInfrastructure::EncryptMessage(unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *ciphertext)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int len, ciphertext_len;

    /* Create and initialise the context */
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) {
        handleErrors();
    }

    /* Initialise the encryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key and IV size appropriate for your cipher. */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_bf_cbc(), nullptr, key, iv)) {
        handleErrors();
    }

    /* Provide the message to be encrypted, and obtain the encrypted output. EVP_EncryptUpdate can be called multiple
     * times if necessary */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len)) {
        handleErrors();
    }
    ciphertext_len = len;

    /* Finalise the encryption. Further ciphertext bytes may be written at this stage. */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len)) {
        handleErrors();
    }
    ciphertext_len += len;

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    return ciphertext_len;
}
```

EDIT2: Here is now my new EncryptMessages with your suggestions:

```
int SecureInfrastructure::Encrypt_BF_CBC(unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *ciphertext)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int len;
    int ciphertext_len;

    /* Create and initialise the context */
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) {
        handleErrors();
    }

    /* Initialise the encryption operation with fixed key size */

    EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_bf_cbc(), NULL, NULL, NULL);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length(ctx, 32);
    EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv);

    /* Provide the message to be encrypted, and obtain the encrypted output. */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len))
        handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len = len;

    /* Finalise the encryption. */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len))
        handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len += len;

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return ciphertext_len;
}
```

Method used for Base64-encoding:

```
std::string base64_encode(const std::string& in) { 
    string out; 
    int val = 0, valb = -6; 
    for (unsigned char c : in) { 
        val = (val << 8) + c; 
        valb += 8; 
        while (valb >= 0) { 
            out.push_back("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"[(val >> valb) & 0x3F]); 
            valb -= 6; 
        } 
    } 
    if (valb > -6) out.push_back("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"[((val << 8) >> (valb + 8)) & 0x3F]); 
    while (out.size() % 4) out.push_back('='); 
    return out; 
}
```

Comment: I've added an answer which shows the output for every method of `openssl_get_cipher_methods()` in PHP. None of the hashes match what your C++ program is outputting. So the issue will be there as opposed to in the PHP decryption, since no other methods are supported. One thing which has come to my attention is where you're telling the C++ script to use Blowfish CBC? I can't see that?

Comment: Inside the mysec.EncryptMessage there is a line that I defined the CBC Blowfish

/* Initialise the decryption operation.
    if(1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_bf_cbc(), nullptr, key, iv)) {
        handleErrors();
    }

Comment: Again, just thinking out loud  - you're returning `ciphertext_len` which is cast as an `int`. Shouldn't this be a string? And from the variable name, it seems like it's some kind of length variable? This should be the string that's equivalent to doing `openssl_encrypt("This quick...")` in PHP.

Comment: The ciphertext_len I am using to describe the size of ciphertext to be used later in the decryption function. The size is indeed an int type.

Comment: The best way I can think to debug it is to output (`cout` if that's the way to `echo` in C++) the variable `ciphertext` in as many places as possible. It looks to me like you're returning something which *isn't* the hashed text. In other words it's hashing something other than `"The quick brown fox.."`. This is why the hash output from C++ is different to that in PHP. Because the input strings are effectively different.

Comment: interesting suggestion... i am trying to do this.
I was also wondering why it is necessary to use the function EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len) in the C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current C-implementation assumes a cipher with a fixed key length, which doesn't apply to [Blowfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_(cipher)). For ciphers with a variable key length that is to be set to a certain value, e.g. 32 bytes,

```
EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_bf_cbc(), NULL , key, iv);
```

must be replaced by

```
EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_bf_cbc(), NULL, NULL, NULL);
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length(ctx, 32);
EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv);
```

in `EncryptMessage`, e.g. [here](https://flylib.com/books/en/2.878.1.85/1/). And analogously also with the decryption. Then the results of the C- and PHP-code are the same.

Comment: Interesting idea... I am trying to modify my code to use this and the results seems to be promissing... In the next week when I return to the office I will test with more details.

Comment: I noticed that now the generated crypt message is:
hWj7F1fnBXhIWv4sonjhSmJgHWJALFecxxrGe0T1kLrN4TfSMUw/uELj6h5+LaphyI27Egd/
It is almost equal to the PHP does. However there are some extra characters because it should generate this:
hWj7F1fnBXhIWv4sonjhSmJgHWJALFecxxrGe0T1kLrN4TfSMUw/uELj6h5+Laph

Comment: I can't reproduce your result and suspect that another problem is the cause. It's noticeable that the length of your Base64-decoded ciphertext is 54 bytes long and therefore not an integer multiple of the BF-blocksize (8 bytes). This also applies to your original (wrong) result. It looks like _more than_ the ciphertext has been Base64-encoded. I suspect the error in the Base64-encoding of the `main`-method, because the length of the ciphertext `ciphertext_len` isn't considered. Maybe you can fix the bug with this info, otherwise please post the implementation of your `base64_encode`-method.

Comment: It may already be sufficient to terminate the ciphertext with `0` before the Base64-encoding: `ciphertext[ciphertext_len] = 0;`

Comment: Here is my base64 encoder

string base64_encode(const std::string &in)
{
    string out;
    int val=0, valb=-6;
    for (unsigned char c : in) {
        val = (val<<8) + c;
        valb += 8;
        while (valb>=0)
        {
            out.push_back("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"[(val>>valb)&0x3F]);
            valb-=6;
        }
    }
    if (valb>-6) out.push_back("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"[((val<<8)>>(valb+8))&0x3F]);
    while (out.size()%4) out.push_back('=');
    return out;
}

Comment: Please check the EDIT2 at the main post. I posted the new EncryptMessage using your suggestions

Comment: Please insert in the `main`-method `ciphertext[ciphertext_len] = 0;` _immediately before_ `string encryptedText = mySec.base64_encode(...`. With this change, the ciphertext should be correctly converted from `unsigned char[]` to `string` and the Base64-encoding should work. Now try again using the modified `Encrypt_BF_CBC`-method.

Comment: All right it worked flawlessly with this solution. Thank you so much for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a PHP developer so can't comment much on the C++ side of things.

However, I've tested this with PHP 7.2.10 and am getting the same results.

If you swap `$ciphertext` to the value you've given `hWj7F1fnBXhIWv4sonjhSmJgHWJALFecxxrGe0T1kLrN4TfSMUw/uELj6h5+Laph` then execute the script it will indeed give you:

"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

So there's no issue with your PHP script at all.

The issue is that the hash you're providing (which was generated by the C++ program) isn't correct as far as the decryption implementation in PHP goes. If you do `var_dump($original_plaintext);` in the PHP script it returns false, which confirms this.

**Whereabouts does your C++ program tell it to use Blowfish CBC?** I can see where you've done this in the PHP script using `$cipher`, but not in C++.

There isn't a single cipher method in PHP which will give you that hash. As a test use this script which shows the method name (from `openssl_get_cipher_methods()`) and hash:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$methods = openssl_get_cipher_methods();
foreach ($methods as $method) {
    echo $method . "\n";

    echo openssl_encrypt("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", $method, "ZdOAq0yn6H1i35TywbLrtqBO4NCjh7Vh", 0, "01234567");

    echo "\n\n----\n\n";
}
?>
```

Output:

```
AES-128-CBC
CFqD8KvYNNSLRRH5leJm9jLq4japdiZODU959rRx4E1IyGcpCfG9VezF0IdsWPDy

----

AES-128-CBC-HMAC-SHA1
CFqD8KvYNNSLRRH5leJm9jLq4japdiZODU959rRx4E1IyGcpCfG9VezF0IdsWPDy

----

AES-128-CBC-HMAC-SHA256
CFqD8KvYNNSLRRH5leJm9jLq4japdiZODU959rRx4E1IyGcpCfG9VezF0IdsWPDy

----

AES-128-CFB
Kjdp5YLSCjWqYRPiWAi7vWJt3ui+NZnJXSL4dBdNEaIWyK2AeQIm2If0Mg==

----

AES-128-CFB1
PsQSrHSFqXuZVZgtNXMSvwsdhhmxfw2MJgPmf/I++n1jmb0QZfRpSulHCg==

----

AES-128-CFB8
KmQC+qe1l5iIeQk4MdBwkQlzvcmNCZH3EhxCCP1P7I2CrZAjE0G0NDQ24Q==

----

AES-128-CTR
Kjdp5YLSCjWqYRPiWAi7vVxK24U+JACgW6KCrbnVwTBQrBy/dUPI6RxNag==

----

AES-128-ECB
TGwrUkmBrlam+I/4nL/KXXILZKdb5FKDpo+BSYMYe+z90MSzX75nkQXhRund4wCF

----

AES-128-OFB
Kjdp5YLSCjWqYRPiWAi7vV7oblWo5p+Us1m5FA0+R8nb7EE3cOXI6O7RCg==

----

AES-128-XTS
Ofhfg4ruiwKduK+6wC01olTA4XVY90bFBYfd+0QJgqs6O2OKrhhd3gRWMQ==

----

AES-192-CBC
9PoANX4yywNkBNFCcX++qXST7xumUwIU0BIAwe4npwLNmeSC7MsYOsawg/+RztyV

----

AES-192-CFB
wjxuTYax9f6jWWvKmidXvucLDzRNR/l5srv5KKVIPphruAhPnKQ23+Vspw==

----

AES-192-CFB1
6jB9HioMtoi3MZky0B8M01W1l2SqR6ZvtL3I8WEClcIdMXYFnjdP50o2Nw==

----

AES-192-CFB8
wvw3vpDpqPTInjIuFEAhWwKlwrekcpc4Q7X7ApRKjHT1a+WDkME7Hz/u3A==

----

AES-192-CTR
wjxuTYax9f6jWWvKmidXvibXdkK8UNq9ZX8bAsh6OcN1jD2UcFHuf0X5IA==

----

AES-192-ECB
bAzuDIkfDbJNXkWNtovgH3UPoh+jRoq1kUxfomAHMPGxDbBWc4bDDrrEvWHkTqYM

----

AES-192-OFB
wjxuTYax9f6jWWvKmidXvspHO1k5ImnLwNgWM+lB6brfjPT78myhmkK35w==

----

AES-256-CBC
jLxnUq0bKY2//CwBFeZoqy3u7s8E7aQ0PEm/5vPHR4/a2TVylXu5n2o2x7pu8SRq

----

AES-256-CBC-HMAC-SHA1
jLxnUq0bKY2//CwBFeZoqy3u7s8E7aQ0PEm/5vPHR4/a2TVylXu5n2o2x7pu8SRq

----

AES-256-CBC-HMAC-SHA256
jLxnUq0bKY2//CwBFeZoqy3u7s8E7aQ0PEm/5vPHR4/a2TVylXu5n2o2x7pu8SRq

----

AES-256-CFB
9cmTuo3iisXBbJzWFWCmgl/7mZ20LODkcqP+GNf7r9zzJy7pskvGE3h8+Q==

----

AES-256-CFB1
y0D9Yj1ymwYVIrQx64nehgeoydPk9xB++McXmSz4lfZbNcBgL0fnlCxvNA==

----

AES-256-CFB8
9bXhDvqzPRmHQ7+8qpp7CxetEMKFzq8FsBJgdcVZPZ+Xno11RbD+l8wAwg==

----

AES-256-CTR
9cmTuo3iisXBbJzWFWCmgqyMguKt3NJv/vh9Z+E/5o7jbmGIjLZKA7+QRg==

----

AES-256-ECB
Xe6luPVXEqvvTVEfNuO281ofcW+uV682D4fYYIyA7KHDcQkVHi647wSFaXqIxwZP

----

AES-256-OFB
9cmTuo3iisXBbJzWFWCmgvMTTvnu1bC8K4cxVlI7G3wxZw6H/z/OU8fUSg==

----

AES-256-XTS
7sP5mx9ES7JypAiqeC+ZXvu70gnNnOiPGMFRhwh14xNZiXRX2/FUTEYKLA==

----

BF-CBC
hWj7F1fnBXhIWv4sonjhSmJgHWJALFecxxrGe0T1kLrN4TfSMUw/uELj6h5+Laph

----

BF-CFB
DtWBgA7jjoOOCHfIg+EvlWURlgrbYWM/001bn4xRbvo9r8sOoOdSAzoTsA==

----

BF-ECB
GEPm0Nw/TGb9XI00QGbMOZhSltrgjLQLcS1rjyLB+Ti8DTfIoDmkvJGqAyoJd0LY

----

BF-OFB
DtWBgA7jjoPFFmYP7IlPTkdCaP+8eY/rgB0M/12zCLTqPHerQV77Ar8L+g==

----

CAMELLIA-128-CBC
iVUMSil3yWiIY9go7atWvrd/mSOtQPKmPnoxYg+B7pwevLuC0Y5RLchGEGn0cgZb

----

CAMELLIA-128-CFB
6HYrCV2MPk3sn3oNWm0xLQarvqJ2dSgRDU/1N0tP0HnA4X+XYEvjd4d7ug==

----

CAMELLIA-128-CFB1
rsMnrvOE/y0VIFH0/SVB5FJG6X6sK6ads+TiH9UM2X42U+hRbqIRT+cdgg==

----

CAMELLIA-128-CFB8
6NRTf6JBm71uVIZzK1DLr799SKaD3UxT5cPFne3xSFuWPb9Mnn2riFz6oA==

----

CAMELLIA-128-ECB
espelBrXu4iWaxp2RZSLPyoSlck4G6ylQYHcu6zITMhmV9sMTEcUcKlZP71HYhQr

----

CAMELLIA-128-OFB
6HYrCV2MPk3sn3oNWm0xLbgO3psDlQMt7zbaA/coaJvIVJqzAaSaY6BSgA==

----

CAMELLIA-192-CBC
uz9Z+IX+P+CpQLBepmI3A9rU6Wcg1CsikKYglNU4SY3hlVOsT6PXD+hKXOobioPZ

----

CAMELLIA-192-CFB
trJ5LHzk0Y/T2TCcR6/daZ78aDxU1dJgRA6+VXU1uqFQovtUo0QRrgiCZg==

----

CAMELLIA-192-CFB1
7LLnnwpBpBkaFXrWw5qegx8KVvEgV2/VR362V5Z43qNJVPzzdvmcFjv9Vg==

----

CAMELLIA-192-CFB8
tiogUjGFA+o7MOCoACibq7PfIaV4Pgj2Js4La4SqAn6262b7b4AAfvUDbQ==

----

CAMELLIA-192-ECB
sn9QfT8PQrMrNxAR9pBT3QVNLdOyhYLKBb1joqmoOW7wzJZ7zW7P070ErkJPkMYU

----

CAMELLIA-192-OFB
trJ5LHzk0Y/T2TCcR6/dafYXU4/u9aln1U/6GzytlRC8Onnw54/t5/slvA==

----

CAMELLIA-256-CBC
Klj37OGl6nexwkw5ZgKSUgTQvAubQYKQeMjX2jMA0LDhaAxr38y91bU3dCwV6xYt

----

CAMELLIA-256-CFB
xlQLgvFHyLYmrl3plKqarQUU8dYdC0Qt0dKg6Z38KQGl0yoh5jIPtzIluA==

----

CAMELLIA-256-CFB1
gxGv92PY0eNcmtYGvdeGKveygkiBiejcckETUkVAVbYXiZO6xvFYnETR0Q==

----

CAMELLIA-256-CFB8
xjARmxeN+O730AwGfWzJaHReUxu28PAzniDHh99SFKnwAww9Iy5wtbpsCg==

----

CAMELLIA-256-ECB
M/P3GH8xSUn4bPPmD7rKupqYS6VG8nSsW65PmvuzZ7L4PJtaOGLMpqx72Wo2F2F1

----

CAMELLIA-256-OFB
xlQLgvFHyLYmrl3plKqardbHfL3lWaw0Ki9U5svO8pXQgTzUJ0jibbOI/g==

----

CAST5-CBC
/XDmMTtfxYk5R+zx0Qg9B0ohoAT0kr/lRJB0OIiM7PlQqMDhM/bH2iF59qYPWn8F

----

CAST5-CFB
qjxQUjVCFHtoSyLDOL6BYUGggJ95TJn0zPD/jevMKetvCjfCOOvWHvmBOw==

----

CAST5-ECB
JZiSJA0Sgs6A+x5U0pffRC/cMgWmHEMptZ4JrLQ5rCvNhLj65aQryWDJDRtesuk3

----

CAST5-OFB
qjxQUjVCFHs3AVHEDgPNF7R40LDHvYDeXna+4QIFWETaoBOplIIcW5BN5g==

----

DES-CBC
VTSvIBHq5AqT3GZ7J3qEt1CGwYCCk7gUpyBTLhgC4kqXdzaOs2TuekAIhmRyZZ9Y

----

DES-CFB
Z6znWp6g7hyOaZpvk9+24Vls+6JaUA+sgIR9h0bWAlqby7oR/fX4k2wy1A==

----

DES-CFB1
fpU6lGqFl6kkQtXuv6XM112vT2CIVEV9iTnSkXd+Zrk7T065215LqO+nzA==

----

DES-CFB8
Z2cEx6sPTs5lDZRq8Ejp2zhR8JbdcoqdKMTHDHA/Q5QA8/B036OKVr3QkQ==

----

DES-ECB
VegFycZ1wAWwrzv0AhpJQ6mFzWr+SK6ecIyqN8iBXfFtXa3eE/4+iSKCEBXCdEfj

----

DES-EDE
bb85G6G8tchhxlIYF8vLpcChFtSC7Iuyywn4tssj7LP/8PHdTWZWKOJDN8NsY3Kw

----

DES-EDE-CBC
0nWlfDQeBtrWN2xZ1JqPl+fTeTfdrp2/bBWFTtpMcsV1Btz8UaN/YPHJ45/qJlrI

----

DES-EDE-CFB
sQ4TEmNrEW2T6C0wYabfGaYpwg69dOE9EZXzA7qt0JGctgiSzXwq3HT11w==

----

DES-EDE-OFB
sQ4TEmNrEW2mZc8ckaETVTWG+AFgiyykc68CWoiwNxuRYyVDCnrYvGS/WQ==

----

DES-EDE3
dzCgZyS9ovD+632p+bJy476BXmaNAKj8qA9xAClHrIgDyaQ0aOhLgFQU9dk7XItN

----

DES-EDE3-CBC
fAngoyT1z6mLk/y1068+0Zr2293p+4K7/JoQu5KRu3WgQJTRVim36ozjqNNIgfbX

----

DES-EDE3-CFB
MTLC8HyTQSkN/kYpDKSnsmFTU2IoW7rQIPMiOKIOiuZiFiYtEULxMyB6iw==

----

DES-EDE3-CFB1
TIfIZ6hK04UUu4IpMeKO/oLDVk3bEVCk2aKlqr7+E2f67NIHsjngE2L7vQ==

----

DES-EDE3-CFB8
MbhxUUq79mYdxFOVcnbM6KqxUOtaeh7tcZSlPsLOOqZrLpTnrlp7HQr92w==

----

DES-EDE3-OFB
MTLC8HyTQSlb6rJ3ranhIqHDnnjplmPB4Ag4asjmyCd8hmMCsWWCpBbXnQ==

----

DES-OFB
Z6znWp6g7hw9YCEYjN1RHjBi6ijkmuQgrI/Q+jywb+cqqm0Zf0p4iunYcg==

----

DESX-CBC
BNP57o24ysgLFrV6f1XHdEdGj3UcGKjepGDs3598A0BiJPpWKhmd4jvYEtIivZXG

----

IDEA-CBC
42f/2g3A7kdWcOe0+OPxcmQPw5Lmazis0nUAJeIzEVVKSkEsW7cDH5fU9z63XY3o

----

IDEA-CFB
ZWg7X3EGMf+FHesNqcZWANkaoW5mPIx4xvTlRqOhcLcDZ9PTF60BqpTTyQ==

----

IDEA-ECB
i+ncikDw1gXTz2wk7iYvlPJaTQfNshfcUcXDhHF7ud4tA3WE4VhBy43MD7u5BIbm

----

IDEA-OFB
ZWg7X3EGMf/fuZ41IQJ+pXIBIu1t5NK81CHarFwPNMFQRFZDAKZi6Vnqyw==

----

RC2-40-CBC
VwYhijuReEDe5vAg51O595EBrjsxWJCvP8iTqp/jqYXVwu/+CmRcNVBo4VX8KpqG

----

RC2-64-CBC
dfo5jOCLZwpSzZE8J1tDKFpwT/6hq6FFjIeeJAufBDanaAFwoDgw5lIaEfHnMbgK

----

RC2-CBC
6kBBW+RF/CbfGWb3/FBmWXz6tSyShVRI3rMoe+YrdkD/CVH/nav9Iz1z46ea/pVa

----

RC2-CFB
g6fHk/fDwnmyHgkxDhcS8uw1MeVYMoTCHc2CxvO07JIiSIa6NuMtJSSuzg==

----

RC2-ECB
RxgWGpaR8wN0KJwTsc6QfEuiqugj9Y0ijqOf2UBuIV1iItfLFqvz8vAyQFkk0gVo

----

RC2-OFB
g6fHk/fDwnnKQZxb5Kj/TvEWj1UNtZYBQGJwVgl/RsNcFR3iilMcW3GKtQ==

----

RC4
zAi3M6pkRBrBrYRy2p+bZ/xOt7dRyfZ/Bp7s0iHfIbPgS2mJij0ll/3V7g==

----

RC4-40
zAi3M6pkRBrBrYRy2p+bZ/xOt7dRyfZ/Bp7s0iHfIbPgS2mJij0ll/3V7g==

----

RC4-HMAC-MD5
zAi3M6pkRBrBrYRy2p+bZ/xOt7dRyfZ/Bp7s0iHfIbPgS2mJij0ll/3V7g==

----

SEED-CBC
MpmWEqpktFNCFlSsRK67o/g8DmUOOCGhiDPSn/zNiRW9Og92hk2BpSpll1TthmY0

----

SEED-CFB
kpvPjDQ4fDAWRde/njkfbmfCdvirZXihMyrpPmpVObIhXai8MEpB3WQdnA==

----

SEED-ECB
Pq5Bdxh1ntX6tW6Vn3QmALx87r6XMGh2O0+lUfbuFYRXblENBn6JIcNp92dutdwk

----

SEED-OFB
kpvPjDQ4fDAWRde/njkfbn8vdtv60gIh96cuJA0LhTuN+UXoZ/9gIw9hNA==

----

aes-128-cbc
CFqD8KvYNNSLRRH5leJm9jLq4japdiZODU959rRx4E1IyGcpCfG9VezF0IdsWPDy

----

aes-128-cbc-hmac-sha1
CFqD8KvYNNSLRRH5leJm9jLq4japdiZODU959rRx4E1IyGcpCfG9VezF0IdsWPDy

----

aes-128-cbc-hmac-sha256
CFqD8KvYNNSLRRH5leJm9jLq4japdiZODU959rRx4E1IyGcpCfG9VezF0IdsWPDy

----

aes-128-ccm


----

aes-128-cfb
Kjdp5YLSCjWqYRPiWAi7vWJt3ui+NZnJXSL4dBdNEaIWyK2AeQIm2If0Mg==

----

aes-128-cfb1
PsQSrHSFqXuZVZgtNXMSvwsdhhmxfw2MJgPmf/I++n1jmb0QZfRpSulHCg==

----

aes-128-cfb8
KmQC+qe1l5iIeQk4MdBwkQlzvcmNCZH3EhxCCP1P7I2CrZAjE0G0NDQ24Q==

----

aes-128-ctr
Kjdp5YLSCjWqYRPiWAi7vVxK24U+JACgW6KCrbnVwTBQrBy/dUPI6RxNag==

----

aes-128-ecb
TGwrUkmBrlam+I/4nL/KXXILZKdb5FKDpo+BSYMYe+z90MSzX75nkQXhRund4wCF

----

aes-128-gcm


----

aes-128-ofb
Kjdp5YLSCjWqYRPiWAi7vV7oblWo5p+Us1m5FA0+R8nb7EE3cOXI6O7RCg==

----

aes-128-xts
Ofhfg4ruiwKduK+6wC01olTA4XVY90bFBYfd+0QJgqs6O2OKrhhd3gRWMQ==

----

aes-192-cbc
9PoANX4yywNkBNFCcX++qXST7xumUwIU0BIAwe4npwLNmeSC7MsYOsawg/+RztyV

----

aes-192-ccm


----

aes-192-cfb
wjxuTYax9f6jWWvKmidXvucLDzRNR/l5srv5KKVIPphruAhPnKQ23+Vspw==

----

aes-192-cfb1
6jB9HioMtoi3MZky0B8M01W1l2SqR6ZvtL3I8WEClcIdMXYFnjdP50o2Nw==

----

aes-192-cfb8
wvw3vpDpqPTInjIuFEAhWwKlwrekcpc4Q7X7ApRKjHT1a+WDkME7Hz/u3A==

----

aes-192-ctr
wjxuTYax9f6jWWvKmidXvibXdkK8UNq9ZX8bAsh6OcN1jD2UcFHuf0X5IA==

----

aes-192-ecb
bAzuDIkfDbJNXkWNtovgH3UPoh+jRoq1kUxfomAHMPGxDbBWc4bDDrrEvWHkTqYM

----

aes-192-gcm


----

aes-192-ofb
wjxuTYax9f6jWWvKmidXvspHO1k5ImnLwNgWM+lB6brfjPT78myhmkK35w==

----

aes-256-cbc
jLxnUq0bKY2//CwBFeZoqy3u7s8E7aQ0PEm/5vPHR4/a2TVylXu5n2o2x7pu8SRq

----

aes-256-cbc-hmac-sha1
jLxnUq0bKY2//CwBFeZoqy3u7s8E7aQ0PEm/5vPHR4/a2TVylXu5n2o2x7pu8SRq

----

aes-256-cbc-hmac-sha256
jLxnUq0bKY2//CwBFeZoqy3u7s8E7aQ0PEm/5vPHR4/a2TVylXu5n2o2x7pu8SRq

----

aes-256-ccm


----

aes-256-cfb
9cmTuo3iisXBbJzWFWCmgl/7mZ20LODkcqP+GNf7r9zzJy7pskvGE3h8+Q==

----

aes-256-cfb1
y0D9Yj1ymwYVIrQx64nehgeoydPk9xB++McXmSz4lfZbNcBgL0fnlCxvNA==

----

aes-256-cfb8
9bXhDvqzPRmHQ7+8qpp7CxetEMKFzq8FsBJgdcVZPZ+Xno11RbD+l8wAwg==

----

aes-256-ctr
9cmTuo3iisXBbJzWFWCmgqyMguKt3NJv/vh9Z+E/5o7jbmGIjLZKA7+QRg==

----

aes-256-ecb
Xe6luPVXEqvvTVEfNuO281ofcW+uV682D4fYYIyA7KHDcQkVHi647wSFaXqIxwZP

----

aes-256-gcm


----

aes-256-ofb
9cmTuo3iisXBbJzWFWCmgvMTTvnu1bC8K4cxVlI7G3wxZw6H/z/OU8fUSg==

----

aes-256-xts
7sP5mx9ES7JypAiqeC+ZXvu70gnNnOiPGMFRhwh14xNZiXRX2/FUTEYKLA==

----

bf-cbc
hWj7F1fnBXhIWv4sonjhSmJgHWJALFecxxrGe0T1kLrN4TfSMUw/uELj6h5+Laph

----

bf-cfb
DtWBgA7jjoOOCHfIg+EvlWURlgrbYWM/001bn4xRbvo9r8sOoOdSAzoTsA==

----

bf-ecb
GEPm0Nw/TGb9XI00QGbMOZhSltrgjLQLcS1rjyLB+Ti8DTfIoDmkvJGqAyoJd0LY

----

bf-ofb
DtWBgA7jjoPFFmYP7IlPTkdCaP+8eY/rgB0M/12zCLTqPHerQV77Ar8L+g==

----

camellia-128-cbc
iVUMSil3yWiIY9go7atWvrd/mSOtQPKmPnoxYg+B7pwevLuC0Y5RLchGEGn0cgZb

----

camellia-128-cfb
6HYrCV2MPk3sn3oNWm0xLQarvqJ2dSgRDU/1N0tP0HnA4X+XYEvjd4d7ug==

----

camellia-128-cfb1
rsMnrvOE/y0VIFH0/SVB5FJG6X6sK6ads+TiH9UM2X42U+hRbqIRT+cdgg==

----

camellia-128-cfb8
6NRTf6JBm71uVIZzK1DLr799SKaD3UxT5cPFne3xSFuWPb9Mnn2riFz6oA==

----

camellia-128-ecb
espelBrXu4iWaxp2RZSLPyoSlck4G6ylQYHcu6zITMhmV9sMTEcUcKlZP71HYhQr

----

camellia-128-ofb
6HYrCV2MPk3sn3oNWm0xLbgO3psDlQMt7zbaA/coaJvIVJqzAaSaY6BSgA==

----

camellia-192-cbc
uz9Z+IX+P+CpQLBepmI3A9rU6Wcg1CsikKYglNU4SY3hlVOsT6PXD+hKXOobioPZ

----

camellia-192-cfb
trJ5LHzk0Y/T2TCcR6/daZ78aDxU1dJgRA6+VXU1uqFQovtUo0QRrgiCZg==

----

camellia-192-cfb1
7LLnnwpBpBkaFXrWw5qegx8KVvEgV2/VR362V5Z43qNJVPzzdvmcFjv9Vg==

----

camellia-192-cfb8
tiogUjGFA+o7MOCoACibq7PfIaV4Pgj2Js4La4SqAn6262b7b4AAfvUDbQ==

----

camellia-192-ecb
sn9QfT8PQrMrNxAR9pBT3QVNLdOyhYLKBb1joqmoOW7wzJZ7zW7P070ErkJPkMYU

----

camellia-192-ofb
trJ5LHzk0Y/T2TCcR6/dafYXU4/u9aln1U/6GzytlRC8Onnw54/t5/slvA==

----

camellia-256-cbc
Klj37OGl6nexwkw5ZgKSUgTQvAubQYKQeMjX2jMA0LDhaAxr38y91bU3dCwV6xYt

----

camellia-256-cfb
xlQLgvFHyLYmrl3plKqarQUU8dYdC0Qt0dKg6Z38KQGl0yoh5jIPtzIluA==

----

camellia-256-cfb1
gxGv92PY0eNcmtYGvdeGKveygkiBiejcckETUkVAVbYXiZO6xvFYnETR0Q==

----

camellia-256-cfb8
xjARmxeN+O730AwGfWzJaHReUxu28PAzniDHh99SFKnwAww9Iy5wtbpsCg==

----

camellia-256-ecb
M/P3GH8xSUn4bPPmD7rKupqYS6VG8nSsW65PmvuzZ7L4PJtaOGLMpqx72Wo2F2F1

----

camellia-256-ofb
xlQLgvFHyLYmrl3plKqardbHfL3lWaw0Ki9U5svO8pXQgTzUJ0jibbOI/g==

----

cast5-cbc
/XDmMTtfxYk5R+zx0Qg9B0ohoAT0kr/lRJB0OIiM7PlQqMDhM/bH2iF59qYPWn8F

----

cast5-cfb
qjxQUjVCFHtoSyLDOL6BYUGggJ95TJn0zPD/jevMKetvCjfCOOvWHvmBOw==

----

cast5-ecb
JZiSJA0Sgs6A+x5U0pffRC/cMgWmHEMptZ4JrLQ5rCvNhLj65aQryWDJDRtesuk3

----

cast5-ofb
qjxQUjVCFHs3AVHEDgPNF7R40LDHvYDeXna+4QIFWETaoBOplIIcW5BN5g==

----

des-cbc
VTSvIBHq5AqT3GZ7J3qEt1CGwYCCk7gUpyBTLhgC4kqXdzaOs2TuekAIhmRyZZ9Y

----

des-cfb
Z6znWp6g7hyOaZpvk9+24Vls+6JaUA+sgIR9h0bWAlqby7oR/fX4k2wy1A==

----

des-cfb1
fpU6lGqFl6kkQtXuv6XM112vT2CIVEV9iTnSkXd+Zrk7T065215LqO+nzA==

----

des-cfb8
Z2cEx6sPTs5lDZRq8Ejp2zhR8JbdcoqdKMTHDHA/Q5QA8/B036OKVr3QkQ==

----

des-ecb
VegFycZ1wAWwrzv0AhpJQ6mFzWr+SK6ecIyqN8iBXfFtXa3eE/4+iSKCEBXCdEfj

----

des-ede
bb85G6G8tchhxlIYF8vLpcChFtSC7Iuyywn4tssj7LP/8PHdTWZWKOJDN8NsY3Kw

----

des-ede-cbc
0nWlfDQeBtrWN2xZ1JqPl+fTeTfdrp2/bBWFTtpMcsV1Btz8UaN/YPHJ45/qJlrI

----

des-ede-cfb
sQ4TEmNrEW2T6C0wYabfGaYpwg69dOE9EZXzA7qt0JGctgiSzXwq3HT11w==

----

des-ede-ofb
sQ4TEmNrEW2mZc8ckaETVTWG+AFgiyykc68CWoiwNxuRYyVDCnrYvGS/WQ==

----

des-ede3
dzCgZyS9ovD+632p+bJy476BXmaNAKj8qA9xAClHrIgDyaQ0aOhLgFQU9dk7XItN

----

des-ede3-cbc
fAngoyT1z6mLk/y1068+0Zr2293p+4K7/JoQu5KRu3WgQJTRVim36ozjqNNIgfbX

----

des-ede3-cfb
MTLC8HyTQSkN/kYpDKSnsmFTU2IoW7rQIPMiOKIOiuZiFiYtEULxMyB6iw==

----

des-ede3-cfb1
TIfIZ6hK04UUu4IpMeKO/oLDVk3bEVCk2aKlqr7+E2f67NIHsjngE2L7vQ==

----

des-ede3-cfb8
MbhxUUq79mYdxFOVcnbM6KqxUOtaeh7tcZSlPsLOOqZrLpTnrlp7HQr92w==

----

des-ede3-ofb
MTLC8HyTQSlb6rJ3ranhIqHDnnjplmPB4Ag4asjmyCd8hmMCsWWCpBbXnQ==

----

des-ofb
Z6znWp6g7hw9YCEYjN1RHjBi6ijkmuQgrI/Q+jywb+cqqm0Zf0p4iunYcg==

----

desx-cbc
BNP57o24ysgLFrV6f1XHdEdGj3UcGKjepGDs3598A0BiJPpWKhmd4jvYEtIivZXG

----

id-aes128-CCM


----

id-aes128-GCM


----

id-aes128-wrap


----

id-aes192-CCM


----

id-aes192-GCM


----

id-aes192-wrap


----

id-aes256-CCM


----

id-aes256-GCM


----

id-aes256-wrap


----

id-smime-alg-CMS3DESwrap


----

idea-cbc
42f/2g3A7kdWcOe0+OPxcmQPw5Lmazis0nUAJeIzEVVKSkEsW7cDH5fU9z63XY3o

----

idea-cfb
ZWg7X3EGMf+FHesNqcZWANkaoW5mPIx4xvTlRqOhcLcDZ9PTF60BqpTTyQ==

----

idea-ecb
i+ncikDw1gXTz2wk7iYvlPJaTQfNshfcUcXDhHF7ud4tA3WE4VhBy43MD7u5BIbm

----

idea-ofb
ZWg7X3EGMf/fuZ41IQJ+pXIBIu1t5NK81CHarFwPNMFQRFZDAKZi6Vnqyw==

----

rc2-40-cbc
VwYhijuReEDe5vAg51O595EBrjsxWJCvP8iTqp/jqYXVwu/+CmRcNVBo4VX8KpqG

----

rc2-64-cbc
dfo5jOCLZwpSzZE8J1tDKFpwT/6hq6FFjIeeJAufBDanaAFwoDgw5lIaEfHnMbgK

----

rc2-cbc
6kBBW+RF/CbfGWb3/FBmWXz6tSyShVRI3rMoe+YrdkD/CVH/nav9Iz1z46ea/pVa

----

rc2-cfb
g6fHk/fDwnmyHgkxDhcS8uw1MeVYMoTCHc2CxvO07JIiSIa6NuMtJSSuzg==

----

rc2-ecb
RxgWGpaR8wN0KJwTsc6QfEuiqugj9Y0ijqOf2UBuIV1iItfLFqvz8vAyQFkk0gVo

----

rc2-ofb
g6fHk/fDwnnKQZxb5Kj/TvEWj1UNtZYBQGJwVgl/RsNcFR3iilMcW3GKtQ==

----

rc4
zAi3M6pkRBrBrYRy2p+bZ/xOt7dRyfZ/Bp7s0iHfIbPgS2mJij0ll/3V7g==

----

rc4-40
zAi3M6pkRBrBrYRy2p+bZ/xOt7dRyfZ/Bp7s0iHfIbPgS2mJij0ll/3V7g==

----

rc4-hmac-md5
zAi3M6pkRBrBrYRy2p+bZ/xOt7dRyfZ/Bp7s0iHfIbPgS2mJij0ll/3V7g==

----

seed-cbc
MpmWEqpktFNCFlSsRK67o/g8DmUOOCGhiDPSn/zNiRW9Og92hk2BpSpll1TthmY0

----

seed-cfb
kpvPjDQ4fDAWRde/njkfbmfCdvirZXihMyrpPmpVObIhXai8MEpB3WQdnA==

----

seed-ecb
Pq5Bdxh1ntX6tW6Vn3QmALx87r6XMGh2O0+lUfbuFYRXblENBn6JIcNp92dutdwk

----

seed-ofb
kpvPjDQ4fDAWRde/njkfbn8vdtv60gIh96cuJA0LhTuN+UXoZ/9gIw9hNA==

----
```

Edit - it looks to me like your C++ program is hashing *something other* than `"The quick brown fox..."`. The best way I can think to debug this - as would be the case in PHP - is to output the `ciphertext` variable in as many places as possible in the C++ script.

Comment: Inside my EncryptMessage() method there is a line that I defined to use the Blowfish CBC. EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_bf_cbc(), nullptr, key, iv)